# Unity: Add strafing to Player Controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

For a few weeks, I've been trying to add strafing to my Player. I now have a working Script but when I try using the Mouse to Rotate the Player and the Camera the script is reacting wierd. When the Player is facing towards the Z-direction the Player is walking and running normaly, but as soon as I turn him around he slows down and moves super slow. Here's the code:

```
    void Update () {
    // input
    Vector2 input = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"));
    Vector2 inputDir = input.normalized;
    bool running = Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift);

    if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.JoystickButton2)) {
        Move (inputDir, running);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.JoystickButton0)) {
        Jump ();
    }
    // animator
    float animationSpeedPercent = ((running) ? currentSpeed.magnitude / runSpeed : currentSpeed.magnitude / walkSpeed * .5f);


void Move(Vector2 inputDir, bool running) {


        float targetRotation = cameraT.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(turnSmoothTime));


        Vector2 targetSpeed = new Vector2(
            ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.normalized.x,
            ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.normalized.y);

        currentSpeed = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed,
               ref speedSmoothVelocity,
               GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));

        velocityY += Time.deltaTime * gravity;
        Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * currentSpeed.y) +
               (transform.right * currentSpeed.x) +
               Vector3.up * velocityY;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        currentSpeed = new Vector2(controller.velocity.x, controller.velocity.z);

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            velocityY = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is `strafing`?

Comment: @derHugo strafing is moving left/right without adjusting yaw. The default player controller rotates the player so as to have them facing the direction they are moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow a player to strafe in the default `PlayerController`, a couple edits must be made. I won't write the code for you, but here are the steps you need to take, they should be relatively easy to implement:

1. First, you need to comment out the code related to rotation
2. Then rather than obtaining the target speed as a scalar float, you should either calculate it as a `Vector2` or as 2 separate floats (preferably the former)

   ```
   Vector2 targetSpeed = new Vector2(
       ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.normalized.x,
       ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.normalized.y);
   ```
3. `currentSpeed` is a float, that relies on `targetSpeed`,  <s>but rather than~~ adjusting `currentSpeed` to also be a `Vector2`, you can use `targetSpeed.magnitude` when calculating the `SmoothDamp`</s>
   **Since you need speed in both the Z context and the X context, you should make `currentSpeed` a `Vector2` Thankfully there already exists a `Vector2.SmoothDamp` so that should be easy to refactor.**

   ```
   currentSpeed = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, 
                      ref speedSmoothVelocity,
                      GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
   ```
4. You need to include the `X` component in the velocity calculation. (remember that a `Vector2`'s `X` and `Y` correspond to `X` and `Z` respectively on a `Vector3`)

   ```
   Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * currentSpeed.y) + 
                      (transform.right * currentSpeed.x) + 
                      Vector3.up * velocityY;
   ```
5. Finally, you want to adjust the `currentSpeed` to include the appropriate `X`, and `Z` velocities. <s>This can be done simply by calculating the magnitude based on a `Vector3` instead of a `Vector2`</s>

   ```
   currentSpeed = new Vector2(controller.velocity.x, controller.velocity.z);
   ```

By the way, welcome to StackOverflow - In the future you want to be sure to include a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and not just the default unmodified code.

People are more willing to help if you've shown that you've made an effort yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick response. I am looking forward to use StackOverflow more and more. I was just able to add this piece of code because it is the only one which works. But in the future i am going to also include not working code so the Community can see what am I trying to do and help me.
Thanks for all the tips,
nailuj05

Comment: So I tried it out and am now using a Vector 2 for targetSpeed like you said I also deleted the rotation code and am now calculating the velocity like this `Vector velocity = (transform.forward + transform.right) * current Speedway.magnitude + Vector.up * velocityY;` and changed the currentSpeed to `current Speed = new Vector3 (controller.velocity.x, controller.velocity.y, controller.velocity.z).magnitude;` but now my Player ist just flying way to the upper left without colliding as soon as I press a key. What have I done wrong. Looking forward to your answer, nailuj05

Comment: @nailuj05 my apologies, I forgot that currentSpeed needs to also be a `Vector2` I've made adjustments to my answer (namely steps 3-5) that should fix things.

Comment: Ok, so i added your changes but for some wierd reason the player still starts to run to the left as soon as i press a moving related button like w,a,s,d.
As always thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @nailuj05 please update your question to show the code you have so far, and I will try to see if I can correct my answer

Comment: @nailuj05 I have updated steps 3-5 again, notice how currentSpeed is now calculated with `Vector2.SmoothDamp` instead of `Mathf`, the velocity calculations have been split  (forward * y + right * x), and we are updating currentSpeed with a `Vector2`, not it's `.magnitude` float value

Comment: Ok, I integratedyour new code and strafing now works but i still want to Rotate the Camera and the Player with the mouse (so you can still turn around). I'll update my code to Include this. Or should I ask this as a new Question?

Comment: @nailuj05 yes that would be a separate question - however I can tell you that standard assets has a MouseLook script, so you should start with checking out that

Comment: @I checked out the Mouse Look script but that is not what i am searching (i think). I created a new question, there i describe more in depth what my problem is. Hope you could help me out there too.